# React to AJAX adding to the page

Tags: ajax, jquery, javascript

How can I have my JavaScript run every time AJAX finishes adding content to the page?

My JavaScript file loads and runs, but only on first page load.  I'm looking for the equivalent of Drupal.behaviors.attach.  Is there such a thing on WordPress?

Comment: What's the mechanism that's making AJAX requests and adding content to the page? I don't think there's one included in WordPress or the default themes. So you're using a mechanism from a plugin? You'll need to find out how to hook into that.

Comment: In this case it was a plugin that used $.ajax.  When finished it fired the "widget:loaded" event, but even after I found that my event handler didn't catch it because their plugin used a custom version of jQuery different from the one my event handler was registered on.

Answer (score 0):

Found this at https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

> JavaScript triggering the `post-load` event after content has been inserted via Ajax:
>   `jQuery( document.body ).trigger( 'post-load' );`
>
> JavaScript listening to the post-load event:
>
> `jQuery( document.body ).on( 'post-load', function () {`
>    `// New content has been added to the page. } );`

I suppose it's up to each plugin to trigger whichever event it wants when it's done or none at all.